# UIButton doesn't resize to fit its titleLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm working with iOS8 Self-Sizing cell and I want the cell resize to fit its `subview`, `messageBodyButton` and `profileImageView`.
`profileImageView`'s size is fixed. As you can see in the picture below, the `messageBodyButton` doesn't resize to fit its `titleLabel`.

Why did this happen? How to fix this bug using Auto Layout?
And when the `titleLabel`'s content changed(say, the model's data changed), how should I update constraints so that the cell height can be calculated correctly?

[image: pic]

Here is my code:

`RXTChatCell.m`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *profileImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *messageBodyButton;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL needUpdateConstraints;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL didSetUpConstraints;

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _timeLabel.text = @"19:00";
        [self.contentView addSubview:_timeLabel];

        _profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_profileImageView];

        _messageBodyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [_messageBodyButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        [_messageBodyButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
        _messageBodyButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        _messageBodyButton.titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_messageBodyButton];

        _timeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
        _profileImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;
        _messageBodyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{ 
    if (!self.didSetUpConstraints) { // set up constraints
        [_timeLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.topMargin);
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.contentView);
        }];

        [_profileImageView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(_timeLabel.bottom).offset(10);
            make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-10);
            make.width.and.height.equalTo(50);
            make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(self.contentView.bottomMargin);
        }];

        [_messageBodyButton makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(_profileImageView);
            make.right.equalTo(_profileImageView.left).offset(-10);
            make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10);
            make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(self.contentView.bottomMargin);
        }];
        self.didSetUpConstraints = YES;
    }

    if (self.needUpdateConstraints){
        // here, how should I update constraints?

    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void)setMessage:(RXTChatMessage *)message
{
    EMTextMessageBody *body = (EMTextMessageBody *)message.messageBody.body;
    [self.messageBodyButton setTitle:body.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.needUpdateConstraints = YES;
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

`RXTChatViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RXTChatMessage *message = self.messages[indexPath.row];
    RXTChatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RXTChatCellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[self alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:RXTChatCellId];
    }
    cell.message = message;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show your code -> get help -> victory

Comment: Please update the question with `CODE`

Comment: Also show constraints you applied for your cell's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Your Button -> Go to Editor -> Size to fit content.
2. Remove fixed height constraint for your button (only set leading,trailing,top bottom) constraint (Superview should be your cell view).
3. This should solve your problem

let me know if it solves your issue.

[image: ]]

Comment: Sorry man I'm not working with Interface Builder, and I tried to add `[self.messageBodyButton sizeToFit];` in `layoutSubviews` but it didn't work.

Comment: @PeteRuan: Well,  you better start using it or all your apps will look like this one ) PS. You did not provide any kind of constraints. Recommend you to spend one evening and learn now to use them in IB, this will pay back with factor x100 in next couple months if u plane to work again on ios apps.